# PHP: how to process this data from database

Tags: php

I'm pretty new to programming so I'm sorry if this is very nooby.

In a dummy database I have a column called currencies. The column has this data:

```
36:USD,74:GBP,68:USD,119:USD,114:BGN,15:USD,32:GBP,1:BGN
```

Above data is the amount and its respective currency the user has paid.

What I want to do is to display a table with each currency and the total amount of sales for that country and also display it in table form.

So with the above data, I want the output below:

```
Currency  |  # Sales
____________________

USD         4
GPB         2
BGN         2 
____________________

     Total: 8
```

Comment: Have you tried using [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)?

Comment: @ChetanAmeta I didnt post code as it's a complete mess, so I decided to delete it and ask SO

Comment: @Naruto - yes, I exploded the data, but i'm not sure how to get them and count them and then total them.

Comment: Well after you explode on the `:` , you need to explode a second time on the `,` and then create an array where the key is the currency.. If key exists +1, else create array element with key X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$data = "36:USD,74:GBP,68:USD,119:USD,114:BGN,15:USD,32:GBP,1:BGN";
$data = explode(",", $data);

$result = array();
foreach ($data as $value) {
    $d_array = explode(":", $value);
    if(isset($result[$d_array[1]]))
        $result[$d_array[1]] +=1;
    else
        $result[$d_array[1]] = 1;
}
$total = count($data);

var_dump($result);
var_dump($total);
```

And the result

```
array (size=3)
'USD' => int 4
'GBP' => int 2
'BGN' => int 2

int 8
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = "36:USD,74:GBP,68:USD,119:USD,114:BGN,15:USD,32:GBP,1:BGN";
$data = explode(",", $data);
$final_array = array();
foreach ($data as $value) 
{
   $new_array = explode(":", $value);
   array_push($final_array, $new_array[1]);
}
$final_array = array_count_values($final_array);
print_r($final_array);
```

Result

Array ( [USD] => 4 [GBP] => 2 [BGN] => 2 )

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my example. I hope its fine for you.

```
$orders = array("36:USD","74:GBP","68:USD","119:USD","114:BGN","15:USD","32:GBP","1:BGN");

$totalData = array();
foreach($orders as $singleOrder) {
    $explodedData = explode(':',$singleOrder);

    if(!isset($totalData[$explodedData[1]])) {
        $totalData[$explodedData[1]] = $explodedData[0]; 
    } else {
        $totalData[$explodedData[1]] += $explodedData[0]; 
    }
}

var_dump($totalData);
```

result

```
array (size=3)
  'USD' => int 238
  'GBP' => int 106
  'BGN' => int 115
```